# Arrays not getting values

Tags: android

I have been working on this yahtzee project and have run into a problem. The dice_number array doesn't seem to be getting the randomly generated values. The oneScore TextView always displays "--". I'm posting my code. Thanks in advance for any help given. Also if you need to see anymore of the code let me know.

```
 switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.rollBtn:
           for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
               randnum = random.nextInt(5);
               if(i == 0){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               else if(i == 1){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               else if(i == 2){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               else if(i == 3){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               else if(i == 4){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               else if(i == 5){
                   images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
                   dice_number[i] = randnum;
               }
               }
           break;
       case R.id.onesBtn:
           for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
               if (dice_number[i] == 1) {
                   dice_count[0] += 1;
                   oneScore.setText(Integer.toString(dice_count[0]));
               }
                   else 
                       oneScore.setText("--");
           }
```

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Use it to step through your code and see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second for loop re-sets the text for each number. So if you have an array

```
dice_number = {3, 2, 1, 1, 4}
```

The `TextView` will be set to `--`, then `--`, then `1` (if `dice_count[0]` was 0), then `2`, then `--`, so all you will see is the result from `dice_number[4]`, which is the last `--`.

You need to either construct a string or use multiple `TextViews` to see the whole array, not just the last element.

Also, the if statements in the first for loop aren't doing anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: oneScore.setText(Integer.toString(dice_count[0]));
That line says to only display what's in dice_count[0]. So I don't see how it would only display the contents of of dice_number[4]. The first for loop randomly generates a number between 0-5 and that number corresponds with an image. The roll button works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a suggested refactoring:

```
case R.id.rollBtn:
           for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
               randnum = random.nextInt(5);
               images[i].setImageResource(image_array[randnum]);
               dice_number[i] = randnum; 
             }
           break;
```

in fact that piece of code that says `if(i == 5) {..}` will never be reached because the value of `i` is always 0,1,2,3, or 4.

Comment: Thanks I didn't need that last else if statement.